# How to retrieve distinct values from multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have a flat text file data which I import into a SQL Server table.

It creates and table with specified name along with multiple columns as per data file.

Now I need a query which will return the data and its count. e.g.

data file :

```
BREAD,MILK
BREAD,DIAPER,BEER,EGGS
MILK,DIAPER,BEER,COKE
BREAD,MILK,DIAPER,BEER
BREAD,MILK,DIAPER,COKE 
BREAD,ICE,MANGO
JUICE,BURGER
```

Result should be

```
BREAD | 5
MILK  | 4
DIAPER| 4
```

and so on.

Comment: What is the schema of your table?

Comment: Are you effectively creating 1 row with *n* columns?

Comment: That's the problem with not normalized databases, everything gets more difficult.

Comment: @Otavio: we don't know if the database is denormalized or not. The data could be transformed in any number of ways during import.

Comment: Why don't BEER, EGGS, etc. show up in the output?

Comment: I am using import/export feature of sql 2008 to get the flat data into a particular table, so its creates columns on its own.

And yes BEER, EGGS will also come accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At a guess at the requirement as would need to see your scheme, but, maybe something like this?

```
SELECT
    ItemValue,
    COUNT(*)
FROM
(
    SELECT
        Column1 ItemValue
    FROM
        DataTable
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        Column2 ItemValue
    FROM
        DataTable
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        Column3 ItemValue
    FROM
        DataTable
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        Column4 ItemValue
    FROM
        DataTable
) UnionDataTable
```

Comment: UnionDataTable is an Alias for the previous SELECT.

Answer (score 0):

This is a wild guess based on incomplete information:

```
select Item, count(*)
from Items
group by Item
```

Comment: Do you think I can achieve this using cursor or similar, because I don't know how much columns would be for different data files?